# How to get TD from next row with same index as current TD

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large HTML table where all rows of the body have the same structure.

Within this table there are editable TDs (which have the class "`editable`" and contain a contenteditable div) and non-editable TDs (which dont't have the class "`editable`" and do not contain a div).

Now I am **trying to get the TD from the next row that has the same index as the current (closest) TD**.

The below code gives me the correct index of my current TD within its row (and looking only at editable TDs).

Can someone tell me how I can get the equivalent TD of the next row ?

**My jQuery:**

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var current = $(e.target);
    var editables = $(current).closest('tr').find('td.editable');
    var count = editables.length;
    alert( editables.index($(current).closest('td')) ); // for testing
    // ...
});
```

**Instead of the alert I am looking for something like the following:**

```
$(current).closest('tr').next('tr').find( /* the td with class editable AND the index matching the above */ );
```

**Example:**
If I am currently on the 4th editable TD in a row I would then need the 4th editable TD in the next row.

Comment: Have you ever heard of [`.eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)? It is the method you need.

Comment: Since `current` is jQuery's object, you can use `current.closest()` instead of `$(current).closest()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [:eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) like

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    var current = $(e.target);
    var editables = current.closest('tr').find('td.editable');
    var count = editables.length;
    var index = editables.index(current.closest('td')); 
    current.closest('tr').next('tr').find('td:eq('+index+')');
});
```

As commented above, you can use `current` instead of `$(current)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ammar - that works ! Still new to all the stuff so I sometimes have to post some easy questions. Will accept as soon as I can. :)

Comment: @keewee279, we are **all** learners. Keep up the good work :)